# discord.js | Reply to Message (Actual Reply with Reply Decoration)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Recently, Discord added new functionality that when a user `replies` to a message, it quotes it and adds a little line that the replier's profile picture with the original sender's profile picture and message, as seen here (me replying to a message from a bot):

[image: Message reply screenshot]

Is it possible to do it with Discord.js?

Currently, I've no problem using `message.reply()`, however the bot just sends a message, rather than actually reply to it (sends a "reply-typed" message), which is what is shown when I reply to a message via the app's GUI, manually (as shown above).

Comment: Chek if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872029/10675707

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Discord.js will support inline replies in version 13, replacing Message#reply with the new functionality. If you want to try the feature ahead of time, please install and test this PR: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/4874. We are always happy to receive bug reports before features are released! (As per usual the ETA on v13 is "when it's ready")]

The maintainers of the djs module have made a comment about this in the official djs server's faq channel. This feature is expected to be implemented only in version 13, if you want to implement this you have to fork djs and write your own reply code to use the [message reference](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) parameter in the official discord API gateway

Comment: Link inside the message: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/4874

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
client.api.channels[message.channel.id].messages.post({
  data: {
    content: "this is my message content!",
    message_reference: {
      message_id: message.id,
      channel_id: message.channel.id,
      guild_id: message.guild.id
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Using discord-reply: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-reply

Main file

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
require('discord-reply'); //⚠️ IMPORTANT: put this before your discord.Client()
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(client.user.tag)
});

client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!reply')) {
    message.lineReply('Hey'); //Line (Inline) Reply with mention

    message.lineReplyNoMention(`My name is ${client.user.username}`); //Line (Inline) Reply without mention
  }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

On command handler

```js
/**
 * No need to define it
 * */
module.exports = {
  name: 'reply',
  category: 'Test',
  run: (client, message, args) => {
    message.lineReply('This is reply with @mention');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Discord.JS versions 13+ you can now use the `Message#reply()` method to send inline replies.

[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply)

```
message.reply("woohoo, inline reply support!").then(/* ... */).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to version 12 of Discord.js, this behavior does not seem to be supported yet.
See: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought - I couldn't find it in the docs.
Do you know if the Discord API itself offers it just yet?

Comment: I think in the next month