# Is it possible for a Discord bot to respond on a message that I reply to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible for a bot to find a message I want to reply to and add reactions to it?

Currently, I need to copy the message ID I want to reply to and send it to the bot so it knows where to add reactions. But the message IDs are long, not everybody got developer mode enabled and I simply want to be able to just show the bot where to add reaction instead of copy paste the message ID.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRqHq.png) I want bot (by replying to message "example" and calling bot function "react") to react with letter emojis spelling "test" on selected message.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to find by in your question? IDs, messages content, etc.

Comment: Added example. Should be clear what i want now.

Comment: Okay, I see. Inline replies are not available on v12, wait for v13.

Comment: They actually are! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114050/discord-js-reply-to-message-actual-reply-with-reply-decoration?r=SearchResults) question