# How do I make a DIscord.js bot actually reply to a message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been making a Discord.js (V12) bot that supports the type of command "say" (please note I'm new to this), but when I use this "say" command and click "reply" in a specific message it just sends the message I've wrote, it doesn't show the original message I was replying at all. [Here is what I wrote with the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Viw7a.png) and [here the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7YbH.png).

My "say" command code is simple because I couldn't find the actual reply function so I couldn't add it (I had to delete content so it's more accurate).

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('p:')) {
      //This line reads the content of the message, creates the variable "say" for it.
        var say = message.content;
      //This removes my message, so it can be replaced by bot's one.
        message.delete();
      //This line deletes the prefix from "say" and sends the rest of the message.
        message.channel.send(say.replace('p:', '')
    .catch(() => console.error('Failed to send - Can\'t send empty messages!'));
    }
});
```

I've found out that there is another way to make a reply. [Here the two: The first one is the normal and the other is by a Tupperhook (Webhook) created by the bot Tupperbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EQf.png)

Is there any way to make at least a version of the Webhook's reply for the bot?

In the case that the Webhook method can work, I already have the way to jump to a message (in this example the original message is triggering a specific command - this would be changed to jump to the replied message) inside of an embed, and here's the code for it.

```
//These should be in the embed command.
//This line recognizes the servers the bot is in.
  var guild = message.guild
//This other line recognizes the channels of the servers.
  var channel = message.channel
//This one sends the word "Message" and includes a link to the message that triggered this command.
  `[Message](https://discordapp.com/channels/${guild.id}/${channel.id}/${message.id})`
```

Is it possible to adapt my code to any of those reply functions? I swear I'm trying this since one month. Any answer is really appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119989/10675707) answer your question?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer! Also, that thread is explaining that there's no way to make a bot send a normal reply yet... So I can leave that part by a side, now I'm wondering if the Webhook method was originally coded by the creator of the bot with those Webhooks, and if that's the case I guess I can't do anything else, I barely know about coding... I can try to make my own method, but since I'm somehow new it will be hard-
In case there's a known way for it with Webhooks, I can make one for my bot, I'll try to investigate more!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in v12 but it's possible with an API request more specifically [Create Message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message).

And the field that allows us to reply to a message is [`message_reference`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object-message-reference-structure)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const url = `https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/${message.channel.id}/messages`;
  var payload = {
    content: "Hello, World!",
    tts: false,
    message_reference: {
      message_id: message.id
    }
  };
   fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${client.user?.bot ? "Bot " : ""}${client.token}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }).catch(() => { });
});
```

Comment: Can’t you use just use `client.api.channels[channeID].messages.post()` instead of node-fetch?

Answer (score 0):

I use a package for discord.js v12 to reply to a message.

If I understand correctly, you want to make something like this?

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaGRY.png)

In npm, install a package called "discord-reply".

```
npm i discord-reply
```

Then, where you defined discord.js, require the discord-reply package. Do it like this:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
require('discord-reply'); //IMPORTANT: put this before defining the client
const client = new discord.Client();
```

Then, instead of  message.send or message.reply just use:

```
message.lineReply('Text goes here')
```

Hovewer, if you don't want to mention a user with reply, use this:

```
message.lineReplyNoMention('Text goes here');
```

As simple as that!