# Discord.js : Move message to bottom of Text-Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to move a specific message (identified by an ID) to the bottom of the text-channel it is in. As if it was newly posted. (This will be triggered by command)

Pinning is not a solution, because that does not pin the message to the bottom of the chat as one might think. It just adds it to a list of pinned messages, only visible by clicking the pin icon, which pretty much noone does unless they're told to.

Reposting the message isn't a solution, because it has a lot of User-Reactions under it, which should remain. I have not yet found a way to transfer all reactions from one message to another, and, looking at the Discord.js Documentation, I don't think it is possible. You can't even fake-react as a user, let alone add multiple reactions at once.

Howevery simply moving a message to the bottom of the text-channel might be possible, although i cannot find a method for it either. But maybe I've just overlooked something.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: The discord api doesn’t let you do this, and neither does discord for people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing what you need the only possible solution is the one I propose below, since discord does not allow you to do what you want to do literally.

Something like this but answered by the bot:

[image]

---

Using discord-reply: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-reply

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
require('discord-reply'); //⚠️ IMPORTANT: put this before your discord.Client()
const client = new discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(client.user.tag)
});

client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!reply')) {
    message.lineReply('Hey'); //Line (Inline) Reply with mention

    message.lineReplyNoMention(`My name is ${client.user.username}`); //Line (Inline) Reply without mention
  }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

On command handler

```js
/**
 * No need to define it
 * */
module.exports = {
  name: 'reply',
  category: 'Test',
  run: (client, message, args) => {
    message.lineReply('This is reply with @mention');
  }
}
```

Credits: [discord.js | Reply to Message (Actual Reply with Reply Decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114050/discord-js-reply-to-message-actual-reply-with-reply-decoration)

Comment: Discord.js v13 has released and replying is implemented in the library. That module is deprecated.

Comment: Unnecessary/Deprecated module, but good idea. Replying to the message is probably the best solution to my problem. That's an upvote from me.

Comment: You can also checkmark if it solved your problem!